# jQuery datatables - select not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

When i apply dataTables functionality on a given table and want it to be selecteable, i perform the following:

```
 var table = $('#table').DataTable( {
        select: true
    });
```

Which is working fine on the first table on the same site. However, when i try to have a second selecteable table, it just won't select on click. It shows the info message "click to select", though.

I have loaded the `dataTables.select.min.js` file, after loading the `dataTables.js` itself. (It works on the first table on the site, even without loading the `dataTables.select.min.js`, but i wanted to be sure..)

I also tried to apply `table.select()` after initialization, it does not work either.

Any ideas on why this isn't working properly?

DataTabels version is 1.10.16, select version is 1.2.3

Edit: My second table is being build on a button click, asynchronuosly via ajax call to get the data, and then using js .innerHTML to actualy build the DOM for the second table. So maybe the problem is, that i do not apply the datatables functionality for the second table on `$(document).ready`, as i do not have the option to do so?

Comment: Do both tables have the `#table` id - if so that's the problem. Use a class to select multiple elements as ids must be unique

Comment: They have different id's. As far as i know, the class tag is used to define dataTables options only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So yeah, the problem was, i did not initialize the second table within a `$(document).ready` function. Doing so, solved the issue.

Thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

Either initialize your tables using class name once:

```
var table = $('.example').DataTable({
    select: true
});
```

or initialize your table separately by using ID:

```
var table1 = $('#example1').DataTable({
    select: true
});

var table2 = $('#example2').DataTable( {
    select: true
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/ffx842ta/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: That's what i am doing. (Example 2)

Comment: @ToniLatenz, see updated example, it works as expected.